# why "-m" and "unittest" when running unittest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

In the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html it suggests:

```
python -m unittest tests/test_something.py
```

whereas

```
python tests/test_something.py
```

seems to work just as well. Honestly, the output is exactly the same with the [basic example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example). What is the point of "-m" and "unittest" there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example contains these lines:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

which do essentially the same as `python -m unittest`: discover and run the tests. You may want to have some other logic there which runs for `python test_something.py` or omit those lines completely. `python -m unittest` will work the same way in any case.